# Adding Google Fonts to Flask

Tags: python, css, fonts, flask

So with flask I know that I can add CSS with

```
<link ... href="{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/style.css') }}" />
```

but if I am adding a google font which usually in HTML looks like

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

what do I need to edit/add for it to work with Flask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `static` here like you would normally for a link to a resource on the webserver. Your link is still essentially static but not related to anything *you* are serving. So you either put the Google font link directly in the HTML template, or as a variable expanding to the full link (which would be convenient if you aren't using the same header template everywhere and may change the font later).

Comment: can you give me an example how would I put it since I am using it everywhere around the website? I am a newbie on this sorry

Comment: `<link ... href="{{ font_url }}" />` in your template. And when you use the template, provide the value in the render func: `render_ template('home_page.html', font_url='http://fonts.g...')`.

Answer (score 6):

Add the google font link to your index.html or any page that you want like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% block styles %}
{{ super() }}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'mystyle.css') }}">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
{% endblock %}
```

Then, add the CSS font statement to your custom CSS file (mine is static/mysyle.css)  :

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;`
}
```

Comment: I got it to work before without adding the `{% block styles %}`, but I guess this is a better way to do it, so thank you!